# When I change button place while using bootstrap it through it in another place

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-4

**body**

```
        <div class="container" style="margin-top: 70px;">
          <div class="formlogin bg-light bg-gradient shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded col-8">
            <p id="signText"> Signin Form</p>
            <div class="form-floating formPos mb-3">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
              <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating formPos">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password">
              <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
            </div>
            <a href="#">
              <p id="forgetPos"> Forget Password?</p>
            </a>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input rememberPos" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
                <label class="form-check-label rememberPos" for="defaultCheck1">
                  Remember Me
                </label>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success buttonPos">Login</button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

when I try to let the form fit for mobile users and computer users everything are okay but the problem is when I smaller screen the btn and forget passowrd and remember me go out from my div and make problem in design

Answer (score 1):

You need to also use Bootstrap classes for responsive coding; for example, in your code, you are saying that the column needs to take 8 out of 12 columns in the page (horizontally). This creates issues in small devices; in mobile, you need all possible width of the device, and it means you have to use 12 columns of 12 possible columns. To do that, simply replace the "col-8" class in the ".formlogin" div with "col col-md-8". Your div will be like this:

```
  <div class="formlogin bg-light bg-gradient shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded col-md-8 col"
```

> 

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer by Zara, You could use...

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 mx-auto">
```

This will hopefully compliment Zara's answer by making your box 12 columns wide on mobile whilst still allowing 8 columns on larger screens, in addition, thanks to *mx-auto* that box of 8 columns will center in the horizontally.